# NameError: name 'min_x' is not defined

Tags: python, anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO6u8.png)

Is there a way to return that variable to a state of "undefined"?

Comment: Hi Sahil and welcome to SO! Please consider reading the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask guide where it's recommended not to post images of code (just copy the code directly in your post)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NameError: global name 'NAME' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751688/nameerror-global-name-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this! I think this will help you out

```
x,y,min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y,X = 10,10,2,9,1,7,10
def visualize(c,x,y):
  global min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y,X
  min_x,max_x = ...
  min_y,max_y = ...

x_vals,y_vals = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min_x,max_x, mesh_step_size))
```

Comment: but i got a new error                                                                                                  x_vals,y_vals = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min_x,max_x, mesh_step_size))
NameError: name 'mesh_step_size' is not defined

Comment: create another variale on the top and initiate with value 10

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables as global inside the function.

Also, you haven't called the function

Comment: I was thinking this, but the OP hadn't called the function, so they wouldn't be creatd.

Comment: Yes the function hasn't been called.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function that finds min_x and max_x, but haven't called it.

Adjust it like so:

```
def visualize(c,x,y):
  min_x,max_x = ...
  min_y,max_y = ...
return min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y

min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y = visualize(c,x,y)
x_vals,y_vals = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min_x,max_x, mesh_step_size))
```